# Issues using Physics2D.Linecast for Movement Collision

Tags: c#, 2d, collision-detection

It's quite possible I'm missing something obvious (I'm still rather new to this) despite checking the documentation, but I'm at my wit's end with this issue.

I'm attempting to add simple linecast collisions to my 2D movement system that checks if there's a wall on the relevant layer to disallow movement, but I cannot get the distance parameter to function properly. It's responding as if my distance is set to the default MathF.Infinity, despite me feeding a float variable into it.

Furthermore, unity keeps giving me this error after I moved my layermask declaration into the Start function: "The name 'mask' does not exist in the current context." I'm unsure why this is happening.

Here's the relevant code:

```
float distance = 1f;

void Start()
{
    LayerMask mask = LayerMask.GetMask("BlockingLayer");

}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Move up IF !isMoving and No collision detected.
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !isMoving && Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, Vector2.up, mask, distance))
            StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(Vector2.up));
}
```

Alright, after working with the helpful people responding, I've updated my code. Unfortunately, my issue seems to have inverted. Rather than detecting collision always, collision does not seem to be detected ever. Here's the new  code (Edited to reflect small change):

```
    float maxDistance = 2f;
RaycastHit2D hitU;

void FixedUpdate()
{
     hitU = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up, LayerMask.GetMask("BlockingLayer"));
    // Move up IF !isMoving and No collision detected.
    if ((hitU.collider != null && (hitU.distance < maxDistance)))
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !isMoving)
        {
            StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(Vector2.up));
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector2.up, Color.red);
        }

    }
```

Comment: In your updated code, you only ever check the ray once: when the object first loads  Then you never ever cast a ray again. How are you expecting the value of hitU to change if you never assign a new value to it?

Comment: I feel remarkably stupid now and have moved that line out of Start and into FixedUpdate so that the ray is repeatedly assigned a new variable based on the current transform, but that has still not fixed the collision issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### Distance param

I think you're confusing the parameters for `Physics2D.Raycast` with `Physics2D.LineCast`. The "distance" parameter your passing into `Physics2D.LineCast` is actually a "minDepth" value. Which according to Unity Docs:

> Only include objects with a Z coordinate (depth) greater than or equal to this value.

Which means it actually has nothing to do with distance in 2D space, but rather rather operates on the z-axis.

###### Solution

I would employ `Physics2D.Raycast` instead. The tricky "gotcha" with this method (at least in 3D), is that the distance param is actually just used by the Unity engine to optimize the raycasting algorithm so unity doesn't do more intersection tests than it has to. It isn't a guarantee for the precise max distance that the raycast hits will return.

You'll have to perform these checks yourself to be sure:

```
var hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up);

//if there was a hit, and distance was less than maxdist...
if ((hit.collider != null && (hit.distance < maxDistance))
{
   //do....
}
```

---

###### "The name 'mask' does not exist in the current context."

This is happening because your `mask` variable goes out of scope at the end of the your `Start()` method. You have to declare your `mask` variable as a member variable, so it's lifetime matches the lifetime of your script.

Try this instead:

````
LayerMask mask;

void Start()
{
    mask = LayerMask.GetMask("BlockingLayer");
}
```
````

Comment: That makes sense for my mask issue, thanks for that.

As for using Raycast instead of Linecast, what would you suggest? I've messed with it previously, but not managed to devise anything that functions. Sorry if that's a question with an obvious answer, but I haven't managed to solve it despite searching this site and others.

Comment: The two methods are equivalent. Use whichever one is more convenient for the parameters you have handy: raycast if you have a direction, linecast if you have an endpoint.

Comment: I edited my code to provide a code snippet solution.

Comment: Do you know if the 'distance' param guarantees distance, I'm almost certain this is the case for `Physics.Raycast` but i'm not sure about `Physics2D.Raycast`....

Comment: So, I've messed with your snippet of code, which looks quite promising, but I've run into what I believe is the same issue I was having earlier with LayerMask. I can't declare my variable in Start without an error "The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code" and I also can't declare it outside of a function because of the same error. Obviously, I shouldn't be running it in FixedUpdate with my movement checks, so I'm at a loss. Should I employ the same concept as the mask solution? I don't know what data type to declare.

Comment: That sounds like you're just not obeying basic C# syntax. If you're declaring a member variable, you need to be explicit about the type, instead of asking the compiler to deduce the type with the `var` keyword. You can hover over the right side of the assignment to find out what type the method is returning (eg. `RaycastHit2D`) and use that type name instead of `var`.

Comment: Thank you for that, it was quite obvious in retrospect. 

I've edited the original post to show my progress and the issue that's arisen.